# iPad mini 3 update iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an iPad mini 3 running iOS 8.3. I'm about to upgrade the OS abut I'm wondering what I will lose. I imagine I'll have to download email and messages again, but apps? Photos? Will safari lose my passwords? Just wondering how much after care this is going to require?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not lose anything when you update iOS.

Just the be on the safe side **[backup your iPad](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht203977)**.

---

**Note:** If your updating to iOS 11, 32-bit apps are not supported and will not open on iOS 11.

Comment: @Rudyard If this solved your problem please mark it as solved by pressing the grey check next to the answer. Additionally upvote by pressing the uparrow above the check mark.

Comment: @Rudyard Glad I could help Make sure to click the *up* arrow in addition to the check.

Comment: Ha I thought I did. This site on the ipad is just miserable. :)